# Transform numpy ndarray with list nested in cells to columns

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a `NumPy` `ndarray` which has shape let's say `(3,)`. I would like to transform it to a `ndarray` of shape `(3, 3)`.

I was trying to do some `sklearn` clustering on the `ndarray` but it didn't work since the shape seems to be:

```
[
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]
]
```

Meaning currently I have three rows, and each of them is a `list`.

Instead of that, I would like to "expand" the list nested to each column. I have googled around but didn't find immediate solution. I guess I'm missing a good keyword here.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you, please, show the expected output?

Comment: The shape that you are showing (`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`) is already (3,3). So it is not clear what do you mean by _"I have a numpy ndarray which has shape let's say (3,). **I would like to transform it to ndarray of shape (3,3)**"_

Comment: Looks like so but it's not. When I print it I get output similar to `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` but the shape is indeed (3,) not (3,3). Maybe it has something to do with my data is transformed from a pandas `Series`.

Comment: Then this is because you have an array of `objects` instead of numbers. Check `dtype` of the array. It is not clear how your data were obtained and therefore it is not clear what is their structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this might work, feel free to add comments/answers if there is better way:

`Y = np.array([row for row in X])`

Where `X` is the original one and `Y` is the "expanded" one.

Comment: It's in the question.